# REST Client throws sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException

Tags: java, web-services, security, ssl, client

I have a rudimentary client to call a REST based webservice and when I run it, I get the error below;

run:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at AE_ClientGET.main(AE_ClientGET.java:17)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:146)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:131)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    ... 27 more
C:\Users\daddepalli\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I see that it is asking about certificates so that it can authenticate itself with the https WS, but I have no idea on how to create the trust certificate.

Comment: i have to imagine a google search with some relevant keywords from the exception will get you a wealth of answers.

Comment: I was able to move past this using the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore option on the project and pointing it to .keystore...however i now run into a problem of authentication...most posts i see talk about using web.xml to implement basic HTTP authentication. the problem is that this will not be a web application. For now, it will be a console application that just gets information and writes the result out to the screen. The future for the app will be mobile, for the operations team to use.

Comment: This is my error output <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22 - Error report</title><style type="text/css">H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} This request requires HTTP authentication.</u></p><hr class="line"><h3>Apache Tomcat/8.0.22</h3></body></html>

Comment: if you have a new question, you should create a new SO post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to move past this using the -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore option on the project and pointing it to .keystore

Answer (score 0):

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {new X509TrustManager() {
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }   
    }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

// Create all-trusting host name verifier
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {


    @Override
    public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void check(String arg0, SSLSocket arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void check(String arg0, X509Certificate arg1) throws SSLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void check(String[] arg0, SSLSocket arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void check(String[] arg0, X509Certificate arg1) throws SSLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void check(String arg0, String[] arg1, String[] arg2) throws SSLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void check(String[] arg0, String[] arg1, String[] arg2) throws SSLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
};

// Install the all-trusting host verifier
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
```

That's what got me past my test. Be mindful, only to be used in a test env.